# Replace only the start character of matching regex

Tags: python, regex, replace

Suppose I am using regex `r'\n[^ \t]+:'` to seach in the sentence. 
It matches with the strings like `me@locmsglhost\r\nSubject: injected subject` and `TARDES.\nLES MANDO LOS REPORTES DE JL\nNOTA: SIN PAROS`.

So I just want to replace only the starting `\n` with space for all occurences of regex in the string.

I have tried several ways but they are not correctly working on different inputs.

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'\n(?=[^ \t]+:)', ' ', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a backreference (`\1`):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'me@locmsglhost\r\nSubject: injected subject'
>>> re.sub(r'\n([^ \t]+:)', r' \1', s)
'me@locmsglhost\r Subject: injected subject'
```

or a a lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`):

```
>>> re.sub(r'\n(?=[^ \t]+:)', ' ', s)
'me@locmsglhost\r Subject: injected subject'
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?